# Springboot: How to override default JSON response structure in case of any type failures?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

In my Springboot(2.x.x) application, while using `REST` Controller, there are two types of failures I need to handle

1. The custom validation failures, here I can generate any Json Response structure as per my need (i.e. any field I need)
2. The default validation failures by Springboot (few examples given below and many more). Here it generates either 5xx or 4xx and default few fields in json response. How can override this at application layer and match to my custom failure JSON response?

```
            MissingServletRequestPartException.class, //it will be thrown when one of form param is missing
            MissingServletRequestParameterException.class, //it will be thrown when one of request param is missing
            MethodArgumentNotValidException.class, //it will be thrown when form json param value is not valid
            MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class, //it will be thrown when request param type value is mismatched
            ConstraintViolationException.class, // it will be thrown when any of request param is not valid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your request and throw Custom exception for each validation error.

Create Exception handler it catch the exception for you and do the necessary work for you.

You can find the code snippet for spring error handling [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)